# Incrementing until number is reached

Tags: powershell

I have a number, lets use `11` as the example value. I have access points that are named (in this instance) `0266AP1, 0266AP2, 0266AP3, 0266AP4` and so forth. `0266` is the site/store number.

By making a call to the Cisco Prime API, I can see that Site 0266 has 11 Access Points. What I want to do to make a real quick list to pass to my controller is increment until I reach `11` or the value of `@count`.

```
Function Get-AllApNames {
    Write-Verbose "Getting all APs for Store $Store"
    $req = "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails.json?.group=$Store"
    Write-Verbose "Making request to $storeApReq"
    $idReq = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $storeApReq -method Get -ContentType 'application/json' -headers @{ Authorization = $auth }
    Write-Log "Making Get request to $storeApReq" -Level INFO -logfile $logFile
    $apIdCount =  $apIdListReq.queryResponse."@count"
    $apArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
}
```

I've removed my attempts as they've all kind of come up empty, but I essentially want to use `$apIdCount` as my stopping point, and `1` as my starting point.

**Solution 1:**

```
Function Get-AllApNames {
    Write-Verbose "Getting all APs for Store $Store"
    $req = "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails.json?.group=$Store"
    Write-Verbose "Making request to $storeApReq"
    $idReq = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $storeApReq -method Get -ContentType 'application/json' -headers @{ Authorization = $auth }
    Write-Log "Making Get request to $storeApReq" -Level INFO -logfile $logFile
    $apIdCount =  $apIdListReq.queryResponse."@count"

    $apArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    $apLoop = 1..$apIdCount

    foreach($i in $apLoop) {
        $accPt = $Store + 'AP' + $i
        Write-Host $accPt
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making mention of `1` being my starting point and `$apIdCount` being my stop point, I realized a simple method of achieving this.

```
Function Get-AllApNames {
    Write-Verbose "Getting all APs for Store $Store"
    $req = "https://cpist/webacs/api/v3/data/AccessPointDetails.json?.group=$Store"
    Write-Verbose "Making request to $storeApReq"
    $idReq = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $storeApReq -method Get -ContentType 'application/json' -headers @{ Authorization = $auth }
    Write-Log "Making Get request to $storeApReq" -Level INFO -logfile $logFile
    $apIdCount =  $apIdListReq.queryResponse."@count"

    $apArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    $apLoop = 1..$apIdCount

    foreach($i in $apLoop) {
        $accPt = $Store + 'AP' + $i
        Write-Host $accPt
    }
}
```

This outputs exactly what I'm looking for.

```
0266AP1
0266AP2
0266AP3
0266AP4
0266AP5
0266AP6
0266AP7
0266AP8
0266AP9
0266AP10
0266AP11
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle this, so I'll leave this open for more experienced opinions for now!

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is called a [`for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-3.0) loop:

```
for ($i=1; $i -le $apIdCount; $i++) {
    $accPt = $Store + 'AP' + $i
    Write-Host $accPt
}
```

See also [this Technet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4542.powershell-loops.aspx) on loop control structures in PowerShell.

Comment: Makes sense to me, as opposed to a ```foreach``` loop.